# Delete multliple records on a particular date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I built a RoR app where I want to allow users to delete multiple items which created_at field matches the date which the user sets in the date field of the delete form. This would be a delete form with 1 date field, and a submit button.

I guess at first I need a custom route in which the created_at date, which the user chose, will be present as a parameter.

Then I need a custom action in the items controller to get the created_at parameter from the route, use it to get all the items which belongs to the user (which means that the user id must be present as a paramater also), and were created at the created_at date. Then use a loop to delete them.
It sounds fairly straightforward but still I would like to know if there is a "best paractice" to make this happen. Like how to properly set up the route for this in rails way?

Comment: a basic delete route would do the trick you can pass params without declaring them in routes file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple if statement in your destroy action should do the trick:

```
# DELETE /items/1
# DELETE /items/1.json
def destroy
  if params[:date]
    Item.where(created_at: params[:date]).destroy_all
  else
    Item.where(id: params[:id]).destroy
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to items_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ryan! Yes, that seems like a good solution, but I still can't come up with a form to make this happen. The destroy route for the item (which is a training) looks like this: /tagok/:member_id/profil/naplo/:id(.:format) . How do I generate a form with the appropriate url(which sends the date along with the member id)?